# Location of data in PNG chunks

Tags: image, image-processing, png, file-format

I was going through the PNG spec to understand the file format and the chunks in it. I understood that each chunk has length, type, data, and CRC fields. In the spec they also talk about each field present in each chunk. For example, the `PLTE` chunk has "red" "blue and "green" fields. Does this go under the "data" field of the chunk? So for `PLTE`, does the chunk contain

```
length
type
data
  --red
  --blue
  --green
CRC
```

as its fields?

Comment: Yes, the individual chunk descriptions refer to the chunk's data section.

Comment: As far as chunks go, `data` can be anything. The interpretation is done by checking the chunk type - and if you don't know, or are not interested in, the type, `data` is just any binary blob of `length` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Note that the `PLTE` chunk has multiple fields: it specifies the whole palette, not just a single colour. Also, if the image uses a different color scheme (such as grayscale or RGBA) then the data stored in the PLTE chunk will be different due to encoding different types of colors. Here's the `PLTE` chunk looks like in a PNG image:

```
[LENGTH] [  NAME  ]  [       DATA       ] [CRC]
         P  L  T  E  Color1 Color2 ColorN 
00000288 50 4c 54 45 000000 000033 [...]  000000e5
```